# |a-b|<|b|/2 implies |a|>|b|/2

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Edit: I was trying to find a general form of the question but I will just put the real question.

My textbook says |a-b|<|b|/2 implies |a|>|b|/2.
I don't see how and the text doesn't provide a proof.

Comment: Is it a+b or a-b... the title says one thing the text says another...

Comment: The title was wrong but I fixed it.

Comment: What happens when $b=0$?

Comment: Oh. I don't know anymore. None of this is making any sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The edited question is true. Notice that by the reverse triangle inequality we have:

$\lvert b\rvert-\lvert a\rvert\le\lvert a-b\rvert<\frac{\lvert b\rvert}{2}$.